# Blackberry http connection to server address

Tags: http, url, blackberry, connection

So I have a HTTP connection class, it opens a URL and returns the contents from that page.

It works absolutely fine on website URLs for example http://www.google.com

However I need to use a URL which is a server e.g http://[server]/[records]

there is no .com or anything like that in the URL.

When I try and connect to the server URL i just get a null pointer exception in the debug messages.

Do i have to format the server URL? I read somewhere that people were concatenating the the URL with a port number or something like that

Comment: Is this running on the simultor or actual device?

Answer (score 0):

I am making a networking post on my blog this week, however I've got what should help you here. I have not finished commenting it or anything but I hope [this](http://dftr.ca/downloads/code/URLFactory.java) helps. One usage example is below.

```
//Other networking stuff I can add here if you need it
//connDesc is a ConnectionDescriptor 
int transportType = connDesc.getTransportDescriptor().getTransportType();
String encodedAddress = URLFactory.EncodeUrl(transportType, _address);
```